# Find a .csv file in directory with header newColor value = 'blue' and return other columns(oldColor, length)

Tags: python, bash, csv, find

I have lots of csv files. I want to find those files who have their newColor column set to blue and for those files, I want to print columns name, oldColor and length on console. How can I do that?

Sample data in files

```
file1.csv
name    type    oldColor    length  newColor
tube1   1   yellow  5   blue

file2.csv
name    type    oldColor    length  newColor
tube9   1   gold    5   red

file3.csv
name    type    oldColor    length  newColor
tube18  1   orange  7   blue
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How to find the files and print the values on console?

Comment: What's the output that you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python:

```
import csv
import os

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(BASEDIR):
    for filename in files:
        basename, ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
        if ext.lower() != ".csv":
            continue
        path = os.path.join(root, filename)
        with open(path) as f:
            reader = csv.DictReader(f)
            for row in reader:
                if row['newColor'] == 'blue':
                    print(row)  # maybe? What's your output?
```

Comment: Thank you. 

It does the job but one thing I forgot to mention that csv file can be in any sub folder for example.

root = /var/www/html/DATA
Under DATA directory i have

Thank you. 

It does the job but one thing I forgot to mention that csv file can be in any sub folder for example.

root = /var/www/html/DATA
Under DATA directory i have

dir1/dir1a/2015-05-26/.csv
dir2/dir2a/2015-05-26/.csv
dir3/dir3a/2015-05-26/.csv

dir names keep on changing.

Comment: @n0mad updated. This will operate on every .csv under `BASEDIR`

Comment: Thanks Adam. It worked. I will be putting more if conditions. How do I do parse column name with space? For example row['cid number'] does not give me anything. When I use a header without spaces, it works.

Comment: @n0mad I'd ask a new question about why your `DictReader` doesn't seem to work with those columns. My guess is that you'll find that your formatting isn't uniform, but it's too much to go over on this (unrelated) question.

Comment: Adam,
You are right about formatting. This is a third part project I am working on it and they needed a quick solution. I do not have control to make their field names uniform. 

I am trying to understand how can I handle the fields with spaces in their field name.

Comment: @n0mad then I'll reiterate that you need to ask a new question, not keep adding on more requirements to this already-answered question! If the input isn't consistent, it'll be much harder to handle the output. Please write up a new question with any examples of input you might get.

Answer (score 0):

Try this from the bash command line:

```
egrep 'blue$' *
```